# how to export static data in Power BI for further use

Tags: powerbi

I use Power BI via the browser.
I can export data of a Visualisation to PDF and powerpoint.
I can export data to Excel, but only dynamic data.
How do I export static data for further use?
to excel or csv
so that i can make further changes, like sorting and filtering.
thanks.

Comment: Do you have the option to "Analyse in Excel'? In the top toolbar, on the left, you should see File | Export | ..., you should find it under Export.

Comment: yes, but that gives me an empty sheet and i have to create the report again.

Comment: Please define "static data" vs "dynamic data". Are you wanting to export all data in a table or matrix visual?

Comment: yes, to a table .  dynamic = the available  "Analyse in Excel'-functionality, that gives an empty sheet and the option to create reports in excel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved : i now have the 'Export data'-option in the list.
solution : i had to request (authorisation for) extra functionality in my company
thanks all, for your help and time and thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

You can hover over a visual and in the top-right click on `...` > `Export data`.

[image]

More details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/visuals/power-bi-visualization-export-data?tabs=powerbi-service#export-data-from-a-report

Comment: that option sounds great. it is not in the list on my version...

Comment: In the link in the answer above, there is a section explaining why it might not be available.

Comment: Furthermore, it doesn't take that much effort to re-create the table/matrix visual via "Analyse in Excel". You can get the table & column names used in the visual from the filter pane.